# bootstrap grid system is not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a bootstrap grid system.

From my understanding:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
     1 of 3
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
      2 of 3 (wider)
     </div>
      <div class="col">
  3 of 3
</div>
```

is supposed to show:

1 of 3              2 of 3(wider)                 3of3

but when I opened it with Chrome, I see:

1 of 3
2 of 3 (wider)
3 of 3

Comment: Each col class is `col-[screen size, (xs|sm|md|lg)]-[width, (1-12)]`. So if you want 1/4 - 2/4 - 1/4 columns, then you would want `col-[screensize]-3` `col-[screensize]-6` `col-[screensize]-3`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have not used proper class names.The class name should be like `col-lg-6` or `col-md-6` and so on.

`col-*-*` is used for Responsive grid (`span 1-12 column`). Extra small devices Phones (`< 768px`), Small devices Tablets (`≥768px`), Medium devices Desktops (`≥992px`), Large devices Desktops (`≥1200px`). Column values can be `1-12`.

---

You will get a complete list of bootstrap classes and there description [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp)

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
  1 of 3
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  2 of 3 (wider)
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
  3 of 3
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/woYWiyhVy4)